# How to type big table in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

Here is what I use.

```
    OS: Linux Mint 18
Editor: LibreOffice Writer 5.1.6.2
```

**Situation**

Consider the following `foo.csv` file (just example, the raw data contains hundred of lines):

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
```

To create a table in Writer with the data from `foo.csv` usually one creates the table via Toolbar and then type the contents (possibly using TAB to navigate between cells).

Here is the result of procedure above:

[image]

**Goal:** Since the whole `foo.csv` contains hundreds of lines, how to proceed?

**1st try:** copy and paste the data from `foo.csv` into the table does not work, as seen below.

[image]

**2nd try:** copy and paste the data from `foo.csv` into the table **with all cells selected** does not work, as seen below.

[image]

**Question:** is it possible to edit an `odt` file in some way to write some code (like we could do with tags in HTML) to produce such table?

Embed a Calc spreadsheet is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the "Text to Table" feature:

1. Insert the csv as "plain text" into your writer document (not into a table, just anywhere else);
2. Select the inserted lines;
3. Select Menu "Table" -> "Convert" -> "Text to Table";
4. Adjust the conversion properties as needed (set separator to comma: Select "Other", enter a comma into the box at the right"):

[image]

5. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> - LO Writer will convert the text content of your CSV into a nice Writer table.

Please note that if you use this solution, there's nothing like a "connection" between the writer table and the csv data. Changing the csv won't affect the writer table. This would be possible only by embedding an object (but this won't result into a Writer table...).

If the csv data is the only content of the odt (writer) file, there's another option: Use **LibreOffice Base** to create a LO Database using the csv file (dynamically updated if the csv changes), and use the **Report** feature to get a tabular output of the csv data. LO Base will store the output layout as report, making it easy to create an up-to-date report.

Comment: This was easy! Thanks so much. Do you know if it is possible to do this in automatic way so that if I change the CSV the table updates automatically?

Comment: @Sigur: Sadly, this isn't possible. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That is enough for me. Thanks.